# Adding times in the format hh:mm:ss with sumif in Libreoffice-calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Suppose I have a column which contains time-deltas in the form hh:mm:ss. Now I want to add those times using sumif and get the total time in the format hh:mm:ss, too. Is there a way to do this in libreoffice-calc?

Comment: This should "just work".  A time entry in a cell is stored as a fraction of 24 hours.  So 12 hours (or 12pm) is stored as .5.  Summing them should be fine, provided you keep below 24 hours total otherwise it will wrap.  What is your sumif formula?

Comment: Ok great, add this as an answer and accept it to get it off the unanswered list.

Comment: how do I sum if the total is greater than 24h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the format of the output-cell to hh:mm:ss